# Problems with onSubmit method of form

Tags: javascript, onclick

So I was trying to make a simple Fibonacci generator in Javascript, but it doesn't seem to be working! I tried it both in my browser (Chrome) as well as JSFiddle, still doesn't work. Anyone have an idea as to what is going on here? It seems as if it isn't even entering the function, since no alert pops up.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

function fib()
{
    alert('In fib function');
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('f').value, 10);
    var o = document.getElementById('o');

    var x = 0;
    var y = 1;
    var z = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 0; i++)
    {
        o.innerHTML += '\n' + x;
        z = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = z;
    }
    return false;
}​

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form onsubmit='return fib()'>
            <input id='f' type='text'></input>
            <input type='button' value='Submit' onClick='return fib()'
        <pre id='o'></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.  First, as David pointed out, you won't actually print out any numbers because the loop will never execute.  Secondly, you forgot to close your first `<input>` tag, which consumed the `<pre>` tag, which is where you were trying to deliver your output.  See this updated fiddle with a working output:

http://jsfiddle.net/6neQU/

Answer (score 0):

1. The input element should not have a closing tag. The element is "self-contained" and should essentially be written as `<input.../>` or `<input...>`.
2. The second input element does not close. `>` should be added to the end.
3. `for (i = 0; i < 0; i++) {`

This loop won't execute because `i` can never be less than 0 if you initially set it to 0 and increment from there.

**Here is a revised version -- http://jsfiddle.net/wrg8Z/**

Comment: In HTML documents (which are the vast majority on the web) the [input element] is `<input ... >`, there is no XML–style `/`.

Comment: 1. I thought in XHTML it was even required for there to be a closing tag, and that you couldn't self-contain tags?
2. Thanks, completely missed that.
3. Fixed that, still not working though.

Comment: @user1580190—you haven't indicated that you are using XHTML (which is extremely rare since most versions of IE can't deal with it). Documents with an XHTML DOCTYPE are almost always served as HTML, so the DOCTYPE is ignored and the browser treats it as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As David says, that for loop you have there won´t work since the increment condition is not valid. when i = 0; and you´re saying "increment i till it is less than 0" that´s not going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
> function fib() {
>     alert('In fib function');
>     var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('f').value, 10);
```

`c` is not used.

```
>     var o = document.getElementById('o');
> 
>     var x = 0;
>     var y = 1;
>     var z = 0;
> 
>     for (i = 0; i < 0; i++)
```

`i` is not declared so becomes global when this line is reached. You are iterating from 0 to 0 so the loop never executes.